# Redis Zset Locate record

Tags: data-structures, redis, skip-lists, zset

Why can redis locate a record in zset in log(n) time both by score and key? Does redis actually store two indexes for a zset?

I thought if we have a skiplist that determines a record by its key, we can only index by this key.

```
SkipNode
   key
     k1  #value
     k2  #score


  |------------------------------>   |
  |-...                              |
  |------------->|-------...---------|
skipNode1 -> skipNode2 -> ... skipNodeN
```

we can only locate a record by key, in leftmost, (k1, k2), order, how can we index a record by k2 only?

Answer (score 2):

> Why can redis locate a record in zset in log(n) time both by score and key?Z

The time complexity of searching by key is O(1), and by score is O(log(n)).

> Does redis actually store two indexes for a zset?

Yes, it has two indexes. A hash index for key, and a skip list index for score.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :-)